# LoadError when starting server for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am following the documentation found here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

On step 4.1, when running the command `ruby bin/rails server`, I get the following error:

```
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/msgpack-1.7.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)\
```

I have tried uninstalling Ruby completely, as initially I did not install the devkit. I now have a fresh installation with the devkit, and get the same error. It is also worth noting I am running this command from the blog directory as specified in the documentation.

I went into my file system and found the file it cannot find at the same path:

```
C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.2.0\gems\msgpack-1.7.2\lib\msgpack\msgpack.so
```

So the file exists, and is at the right location.

What gives? I have tried manually uninstalling and installing msgpack with `gem install msgpack`, but that didn't change anything. Ruby is in the PATH variable for my machine as well, as: `C:\Ruby32-x64\bin`. I am running on Windows 11, so I am following all the notes for Windows machines in the documentation. I have updated with `gem update`, and still same error.

`ruby --version` returns `ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]`, but `gems --version` returns the same error that this post is about. If I try to uninstall rails with `gem uninstall rails` I get:

```
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/stringio-3.0.8/lib/stringio.so (LoadError)
```

I am completely new to Ruby and Rails, so any and all help and pointers is greatly appreciated.